# Queue ADT exam practice

Tags: algorithm, queue

This is an exam question i'm working through, i understand the theory but i'm not to sure about the code.

A queue is to be held in a linear array called Q with number of elements = limit
(numbered 0 to limit-1). The oldest element of the queue is to be held in array
element 0 (at the front), the next in array element 1, and so on. A variable called back
stores the index of the array element containing the newest element in the queue
(or -1 for an empty queue).

What is the pseudo-code for the remove operation?

What is the pseudo-code for the size operation?

Comment on the efficiency of your implementation for the remove and size
operations.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code for remove operation:

```
if back = -1
  error (Queue is empty)
else
  decrease back by 1
```

Pseudo-code for size operation:

```
size = value of back + 1
```

Efficiency : Order(1) or Constant time

Answer (score 0):

I think there also should be a variable `front` which stores the front of the queue. So, we can get the first elment by `Q[front]`.

In this way:

1. Remove operation

       `if(front<=back) {
           returnValue = Q[front];
           front++;
           return returnValue;
       }`
2. Size operation

       `return back-front+1;`

Both time complexity are O(1).